# How do I check for valid relationship between models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a **Group** model where several relationships are defined. Now I want browse groups by various parameters. For example a group can have an "Interest" which is defined as relationship in the model. So if I select a particular interest it should show all the related groups.

```
public function browse(Request $request)
    {
        // $browseField is the field we are browsing against, $fieldId is the primary key for that relationship 
        // I want $browseField to be a valid relationship
        $browseField = $request->browseField;
        $fieldId = $request->fieldId;

        $groups = \App\Group::whereHas($browseField, function($q) use($fieldId) {
            $q->where('id', $fieldId);
        })->get();

        $data = ['groups' => $groups];
        return $this->sendResponseData($data);
    }
```

Now I didn't want to define the same process for every relationship and took the relationship name as parameter.

Now this works if correct `$browseField` is valid relationship. But how do I check if the relationship actually exists. And should I do the filtering this way or there are any better way?

**Edit**

To better explain what I want to do, 
Groups have "Age Group", "Ethnicity" etc. If  I want to browse by age group, I would supply `$browseField = ageGroup` (`ageGroup` is the relationship), `$browseField = ethnicity` for browsing by ethnicity. Now if someone decides to supply `$browseField = asfasf` which is invalid, the code would throw an error. This is what i want to prevent

Comment: From what it sounds like, you would be better off using `Interest::belongsToMany('Group');` in your Interests model

Comment: If you do MVC right, you never need to check connection between model classes, you explicitly provide that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

```
$group = new \App\Group();

if (method_exists($group, $browseField)) {
    $groups = $group->whereHas($browseField, function($q) use($fieldId) {
        $q->where('id', $fieldId);
    })->get();
}
```